# When is a signal handled and why does some info freeze up?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-trap

1. Open a terminal named "termA", and run the created file `callback.sh`  with `/bin/bash callback.sh`.

   ```
   cat  callback.sh
   #!/bin/bash
   myCallback() {
       echo "callback function called at $(date)"
   }
   trap myCallback SIGUSR1
   sleep 20
   ```
2. Open a new terminal named "termB" and run:

   ```
   pkill -USR1  -f  callback.sh
   ```

Something as below is shown after 20 seconds in termA; it's never shown in termA instantly:

```
callback function called at Mon Nov 19 08:21:52 HKT 2018
```

The conclusion verified that when Bash is executing an external command in the foreground, it does not handle any signals received until the foreground process terminates (see [signal trap](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap)).

Make a little change in `callback.sh`:

```
cat  callback.sh
#!/bin/bash
myCallback() {
    echo "callback function called at $(date)"
}
trap myCallback SIGUSR1
while true; do
    read -p  "please input something for foo: " foo
done
```

Add an infinite while loop and remove `sleep 20`.

1. Open a terminal named "termA" and run the created file `callback.sh` with `/bin/bash callback.sh`; the first time, the info pops up instantly.

   ```
   please input something for foo:
   ```
2. Open a new terminal named "termB" and run `pkill -USR1  -f  callback.sh`; the first time, the info pops up instantly in termA.

   ```
   callback function called at Mon Nov 19 09:07:14 HKT 2018
   ```

**Issue 1:** `callback.sh` contains an infinite while loop. How does that explain the following?

> it does not handle any signals received until the foreground process terminates

In this case, the foreground process never terminates.

Go on in termB, run `pkill -USR1  -f  callback.sh` for the second time.

```
callback function called at Mon Nov 19 09:07:14 HKT 2018
```

The info above pops up instantly in termA again.

**Issue 2:** No `please input something for foo:` shown in termA,
go to termB, run `pkill -USR1  -f  callback.sh` for the third time,
the following info is shown in termA again.

```
callback function called at Mon Nov 19 09:07:24 HKT 2018
```

Still no `please input something for foo:` is shown in termA.
Why does the info `please input something for foo:` freeze up?

Comment: Note it is bad practice to name scripts ending with a `.sh`. It makes the caller dependant on the implementation language ( a rewrite, will affect all callers). And you don't need to run with `/bin/bash` (just make the script executable), that is what the `#!…` is for.

Comment: Read also [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before explaining out your problem, a bit of context on how `read` command works. It reads in input data from `stdin` until `EOF` is encountered. It is safe to say the call to `read` command is non-blocking when it comes to reading from on-disk files. But when `stdin` is connected to the terminal, the command will block until the user types something.

#### How signal handlers work?

A simple explanation on how signal handling works. See the below snippet in `C` which just acts on `SIGINT` ( aka. `CTRL+C`)

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

/* signal handler definition */
void signal_handler(int signum){
  printf("Hello World!\n");
}

int main(){
  //Handle SIGINT with a signal handler
  signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
  //loop forever!
  while(1);
}
```

It will register the signal handler and then will enter the infinite loop. When we hit `Ctrl-C`, we can all agree that the signal handler `signal_handler()` should execute and `"Hello World!"` prints to the screen, but the program was in an infinite loop. In order to print `"Hello World!"` it must have been the case that it broke the loop to execute the signal handler, right? So it should exit the loop as well as the program. Let's see:

```
gcc -Wall -o sighdl.o signal.c
./sighdl.o 
^CHello World!
^CHello World!
^CHello World!
^CHello World!
^CHello World!
^CHello World!
^CHello World!
^CHello World!
^CHello World!
```

As the output indicates, every time we issued `Ctrl-C`, `"Hello World!"` prints, but the program returns to the infinite loop. It is only after issuing a `SIGQUIT` signal with `Ctrl-\` did the program actually exit. Depending on your `ulimit` settings, it would dump a core or print out the signal number received.

While the interpretation that the loop would exit is reasonable, it doesn't consider the primary reason for signal handling, that is, asynchronous event handling. That means the signal handler acts out of the standard flow of the control of the program; in fact, the whole program is saved within a context, and a new context is created just for the signal handler to execute in. Once the signal handler has completed its actions, the context is switched back and the normal execution flow starts (i.e. the `while(1)`).

To answer your questions,

> The conclusion verified that When bash is executing an external command in the foreground, it does not handle any signals received until the foreground process terminates

The key thing to note here is the **external** command part. In the first case, where `sleep` is an external process but in the second case, `read` is a built-in from the shell itself. So the propagation of the signal to these two differs in both these cases

```
type read
read is a shell builtin
type sleep
sleep is /usr/bin/sleep
```

> 1.Open a terminal,named termA ,and run the created file callback.sh with /bin/bash callback.sh for first time,the info pop up instantly.

Yes, this behavior is expected. Because at this time only the function is defined and the trap handler is registered to the function `myCallback` and the signal is not yet received in the script. As the execution sequence goes, the message from the `read` prompt is thrown for the first time.

> 2.Open a new terminal ,named termB and run `pkill -USR1 -f callback.sh` first time,the info pop up instantly in termA

Yes, while the `read` command is waiting for string followed by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key pres which signals the `EOF`, it receives a signal `SIGUSR1` from the other terminal, the current execution context is saved and the control is switched the signal handler which prints the string with the current date.

As soon as the handler finishes executing, the context resumes to the `while` loop in which the `read` command is still waiting for an input string. Until the `read` command is successful, all subsequent signal traps would just print the string inside the signal handler.

> Go on in termB,run `pkill -USR1 -f callback.sh` the second time.

Same as explained previously, the `read` command is not complete for once in your while loop, only if it is successful reading a string, the next iteration of the loop would start and a new prompt message would be thrown.

---

Image source: The Linux Programming Interface by Michael KerrisK

Comment: I'm pretty sure `printf()` isn't one of the functions that can be safely called in a signal handler, which means your program has undefined behaviour.  So we can't all agree that `"Hello World!"` will be printed, or that you'll remain untormented by those infamous nasal demons...

Comment: @TobySpeight *I'm pretty sure `printf()` isn't one of the functions that can be safely called in a signal handler*  There's no doubt about it - strictly speaking, `printf()` can't be called from a signal handler.  Per [the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4p4): "The functions in the standard library are not guaranteed to be reentrant and may modify objects with static or thread storage duration."  [Footnote 188](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188) adds: "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."

Comment: @TobySpeight (cont) [POSIX, however, specifies a list of functions that can be called from a signal handler](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03): "The following table defines a set of functions that shall be async-signal-safe. Therefore, applications can call them, without restriction, from signal-catching functions."  Note that `printf()` is **not** on that list. (Note that `fork()` is on that list, but [`fork()` is broken on Linux](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1422161))

Answer (score 3):

> The conclusion verified that When bash is executing an external command in the foreground, it does not handle any signals received until the foreground process terminates.

`bash` *does* handle the signals at `C` / implementation level, but will not run the handlers set with `trap` until the foreground process has terminated. That's required by the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11):

> `When a signal for which a trap has been set is received while the shell is waiting for the completion of a utility executing a foreground command, the trap associated with that signal shall not be executed until after the foreground command has completed.`

Notice that the standard makes no difference between builtins and external commands; in the case of a "utility" like `read`, which is not executed in a separate process, it's not obvious whether a signal occurs in its "context" or in that of the main shell, and whether a handler set with `trap` should be run before or after the `read` returns.

> issue 1:callback.sh contains a infinite while loop,how to explain it does not handle any signals received until the foreground process terminates.,in this case the foreground process never terminates.

That's wrong. `bash` is not executing the `while` loop in a separate process. Since there's no foreground process `bash` is waiting on, it can run any handler set with `trap` immediately. If `read` were an external command, that and not `while` would be the foreground process.

> issue2: No `please input something for foo: shown` in termA;
>
> go to termB, run `pkill -USR1 -f callback.sh` the third time.
>
> The following info shown in termA again: `callback function called at Mon Nov 19 09:07:24 HKT 2018`
>
> Still no `please input something for foo:` shown in termA.
>   Why the info `please input something for foo:` freeze up?

It doesn't freeze up. Just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will show up again.

It's simply that

a) `bash` will restart the `read` builtin *in place* when interrupted by a signal -- it won't return and go again through the `while` loop

b) it will not re-display the prompt set with `-p` in that case.

Notice that `bash` won't even show the prompt again in the case where a `SIGINT` from the keyboard was handled, even if it does discard the string read so far from the user:

```
$ cat goo
trap 'echo INT' INT
echo $$
read -p 'enter something: ' var
echo "you entered '$var'"

$ bash goo
24035
enter something: foo<Ctrl-C>^CINT
<Ctrl-C>^CINT
<Ctrl-C>^CINT
bar<Enter>
you entered 'bar'
```

That will print `you entered 'foobar'` if the signal was sent from another window with `kill -INT <pid>` instead of with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> from the terminal.

All the stuff in this last part (how `read` is interrupted, etc) is very `bash` specific. In other shells like `ksh` or `dash`, and even in `bash` when run in POSIX mode (`bash --posix`), any handled signal will actually interrupt the `read` builtin. In the example above, the shell will print `you entered ''` and exit after the first ^C, and if the `read` is called from a loop, the loop will be restarted.

Answer (score 1):

termA does not freeze up. It is just displaying the callback in the input box. Simply push the `Enter` key to continue with the input.